# How to map values into a non-empty field using \DeclareSourcemap

Tags: biblatex, biber

For my publication list I want to generate several bibliographies that are automatically disciminated by the publication state. For the publication state I use the `pubstate` field and by the `keywords= {own}` field I have marked them in my bibliography database as my own publications (surprise, eh?). The bibliographies are restricted to my own publications by the `keyword = own` options.

As the filter functions of `biblatex` are only working on some specific fields where `pubstate` is not among them, I want to map the content of the `pubstate` field into the `keywords` field via the `\DeclareSourcemap` command. From there I could filter the bibliography according to that field.  Unfortunately, no matter if I use the `append` option of `\DeclareSourcemap` or not, it seems as if there is nothing written into a field that is not empty. If I instead try to map into an empty field (comment the line starting with `fieldset=keywords` and uncomment the line below) then the field is containing the desired value afterwards.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{inpress,
    author = {A. Uthor},
    title = {Yay, they accepted my article},
    keywords = {own},
    pubstate = {inpress},
    year = {2014},
    journal = {Journal of Universal Acceptance}
}

@article{submitted,
    author = {A. Uthor},
    title = {Look, I've written a nice manuscript, would you publish it? Pleeease?},
    keywords = {own},
    pubstate = {submitted},
    year = {2014},
    journal = {Journal of Doubtful Acceptance}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map{
            \step[fieldsource=pubstate, match={inpress},
                fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={inpress}, append]
%               fieldset=note, fieldvalue={inpress}, append]
        }
    }
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[keyword=inpress, title = {Articles in press}]
\printbibliography[keyword=own, title = {Submitted articles}]
\end{document}
```

Of course I could just do this manually in different ways but I'd like to understand, why it doesn't work as I expect it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you need to specify `overwrite` in the map.  Try this:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=pubstate, match={inpress},
                fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={inpress}, append]
%               fieldset=note, fieldvalue={inpress}, append]
        }
    }
}
```

BUT, Also you need to add the `comma` that separate the keywords, because the above code make `owninpress`.

It is possible that the below code is useful for you. It append the all `pubstate` in the `keywords` field.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
    \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
        \map[overwrite]{
            \step[fieldsource=pubstate,final]
            \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
            \step[fieldset=keywords, origfieldval, append]
        }
    }
}
```

The above code make in the keywords: `own, inpress` and `own, submitted`.

Comment: I finally have transferred your solution from my MWE to my real world application and there I have a small flaw arising: If the an entry has neither a `keywords` nor a `pubstate` field, `biber` throws the following warning: "The field 'keywords' in entry 'XXX' cannot be null, deleting it". This is not a major issue as it does not prevent the function, but is quite annoying in a .bib file with some hundred entries. Can this somehow be prevented, maybe by restricting the action to entries where `pubstate` is defined?

Comment: @BenediktBauer,In the `DeclareSourcemap` Add `final` in the end of `\step[fieldsource=pubstate]`. This means, like this `\step[fieldsource=pubstate, final]` .  I'm going to edit the answer for add this.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a solution for the question, but to the problem. Instead of adding the `inpress` keyword  to the `keyword` biblatex field, one can define a new bibcheck and use the `check` option of `\printbibliography`.

```
\defbibcheck{inpress}{
  \iffieldequalstr{pubstate}{inpress}{}{\skipentry}
}
```

and then

```
\printbibliography[check=inpress]
```