# Copying keywords from one BibTeX field to another using DeclareSourcemap doesn't work

Tags: biblatex

My BibTeX entries have a `keywords` field with keywords describing the content.  I also have a field called `tags` with meta information like *talk*, *manuscript*, *own*, etc.  Example:

```
@inproceedings{MalsburgVasishth2007ECEM,
  author = {von der Malsburg, Titus and Vasishth, Shravan},
  title = {A Time-Sensitive Similarity Measure for Scanpaths},
  crossref = {ECEM2007},
  keywords = {eyetracking, scanpaths, method},
  tags = {poster, own}
}
```

Using `printbibliography`, I can filter entries with certain keywords

```
`\printbibliography[keyword=eyetracking]
```

but I also want to filer entries with certain tags.  For example, I'd like to have a section in my CV that lists my posters.  How can I achieve this?

I suppose one solution would be to append the content of the `tags` field to the `keywords` field using a `DeclareSourcemap` contraption.   [Such a solution was given before](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66318/use-custom-tags-to-split-bibliography) but it doesn't work as expected.  Here is a MWE:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibliography.bib}
@article{MalsburgEtAl2014,
  author = {von der Malsburg, Titus and Kliegl, Reinhold and Vasishth, Shravan},
  title = {Determinants of Scanpath Regularity in Reading},
  journal = {Cognitive Science},
  year = {2014},
  keywords = {eyemovements, method, parsing, scanpaths, corpus},
  tags = {article, own}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
       \step[fieldsource=tags, fieldtarget=keywords]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\section{Publications}
\nocite{MalsburgEtAl2014}
\printbibliography[keyword=article,notkeyword=submitted,keyword=own,heading=none]
\end{document}
```

When I compile this, I get the following error messages:

```
Package biblatex Warning: Keyword 'article' not found on input line 34.
Package biblatex Warning: Keyword 'own' not found on input line 34.
LaTeX Warning: Empty bibliography on input line 34.
```

Also, the reference is not shown in the PDF.

Comment: @Ludenticus this looks indeed like the solution but unfortunately it doesn't work.  The results I get with the proposed definition of DeclareSourcemap (adapted to my field name) is the same as without it: `Keyword 'poster' not found on input line 258`. I suppose I should come up with a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @tmalsburg I just realized that we actually closed the question while you seem not to be satisfied with the duplicate. Please, could you explain (the best would be a MWE of course) that the solution to the other question doesn't work, and then [ping us in the chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) so that we can re-open it if we see it's really not trivial? That would be the easiest way to go now I think :)

Comment: Well, if I knew why it doesn't work, I wouldn't need ask here.  In the meantime, I also tried the approach described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203346/how-to-map-values-into-a-non-empty-field-using-declaresourcemap) but that didn't work either.  I'll compile a MWE ...

Comment: @yo' I updated the question and added a MWE.  I requested reopening of the question in the chat but didn't get a response.  Could you please ...? Thanks.

Comment: @tmalsburg Sorry I wasn't there just now. I have voted for reopening. Your edit triggered the review system, so actually 5 people have voted for reopening and it's open now! :)

Comment: You are just missing one important option to `\map`: as the `keywords` field already exists, you will have to overwrite it: so make `\map{` into `\map[overwrite]{`. If you do not want to overwrite the field, but to append, have a look at jon's more elaborate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This is a revised solution. Thanks to @moewe for pointing out how to simplify it.)

Basically, what you want to do is copy your `tags` field to the `keywords` field, but *after* also adding a comma so the final keyword is not run together with the first word from the tags field.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{MalsburgEtAl2014,
  author = {von der Malsburg, Titus and Kliegl, Reinhold and Vasishth, Shravan},
  title = {Determinants of Scanpath Regularity in Reading},
  journal = {Cognitive Science},
  year = {2014},
  keywords = {eyemovements, method, parsing, scanpaths, corpus},
  tags = {article, own},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map[overwrite]{
       \step[fieldsource=tags,]
       \step[fieldset=keywords, fieldvalue={,}, append]
       \step[fieldset=keywords, origfieldval, append]
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}
\section{Publications}
\nocite{MalsburgEtAl2014}
\printbibliography[keyword=article, notkeyword=submitted, keyword=own,
heading=none]
\end{document}
```

Note that Biber and BibTeX will ignore fields they don't recognize. So your `tags` field is copied, but subsequently 'lost'. (You can 'save' it with a judicious use of the `\DeclareDatamodelFields` command, but it is not needed for this application.)

Comment: I think the main part is your improved sourcemapping command (i.e. using `append`), `\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=field,datatype=literal]{tags}` is not necessary for Biber to be able to perform sourcemappings. If you want to preserve all original `keywords` the `final` in the final line ought to be an `append` I think.

Comment: @moewe -- You are right, as always. I added that the .dbx part when I was having trouble because I was forgetting to add the stupid comma.  Then I forgot to check that it wasn't actually needed! @tmalsburg -- Will do, later today.  Note that the `tags` field will be lost without the `.dbx`, which is OK if you just want it translated to the `keywords` field, but may be worth noticing nonetheless.